# Django Post Request return 405 Method not allowed Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, http-post

I'm working on a Django(1.10) project in which I'm sending a post request to a view but it returns `405 Method not allowed` error.

Here's my **urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='Unmundonuevo/index.html')),
url(r'^contactUs/$', views.ContactFormView.as_view(), name='ContactUs'),
```

]

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'ContactUs' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Name" required="">
           <input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Email ID" required="">
           <input type="text" name="subject" id="id_subject" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Subject" required="">
     </div>
     <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required=""></textarea>
     <button type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit" class="btn center-block">Send message</button>
                    
</form>
```

Here are my **forms.py:**

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message')
        model = models.ContactModel
```

And, here's my **views.py:**

```
class ContactFormView(CreateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print('Get post req')
            form = ContactForm()
            if form.is_valid():
                print('Valid form')
                return 'Success'
            return 'failed'
```

It returns:

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /contactUs/
>
> [11/Aug/2018 05:47:58] "POST /contactUs/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your urls.py missing a parenthesis in `as_view()` (>> `ContactFormView.as_view`) ....Is that a typo?

Comment: `url: '{% url 'contact' %}',` shouldn't be `url: "{% url 'contact' %}",`?

Comment: Hi @guillermochamorro, Still return the same error!